# Nuxt axios cannot handle the server sesponse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am new to `Nuxt.js` and I am faced with a strange kind of issue. I have an endpoint in my backend API, allowing the end user to send a `token` and a new `password` and reset the user password.

While the request is sent correctly, and the server responding with the correct data:

[image]

In the `Nuxt.js` side, I have an issue, with the response data.

So, to handle all the HTTP requests using the axios, I have a class like that:

```
class WebAPI {
    // $axios is the instance used in the Nuxt.js context
    constructor($axios) {
        this.$http = $axios;
    }

    async call(config) {
        try {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM. THE FOLLOWING CONSOLE.LOG
            // IT RETURNS undefined WHILE THE NETWORK RESPONSE
            // RETURNS WITH DATA
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            const result = await this.$http(config);
            console.log(result);
            // ...
        } catch( e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this class like:

```
const data = {
    token,
    new_password
};

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url   : '/reset-password',
    data
};

return this.webApi.call(options);
```

But as you probably see, in the `WebAPI` service, the response of the axios is `undefined`.

Also, it worths to mention, that the exact same `WebAPI` class working perfectly with other API Requests I do throughout the application.

Could you help with that issue? Do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using axios wrong. Try use `$request` method, like that:

```
async call(config) {
  try {
    const result = await this.$http.$request(config);
    console.log(result);
    // ...
  } catch( e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: They're using it right, both yours and the OP's call the same method https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api

Comment: Maybe the same. Or not. Nuxt `$http` not the same `axios` as well. Nuxt use `$` prefix for methods like get, post and so on. In that methods it returns `response.data`. https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/blob/master/lib/plugin.js

Comment: @AlexanderYakushev thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. On top of that, as I explain in my description, I use that same WebAPI code for other requests and the other requests are working properly.

Comment: Is the HTTP code of response 200 or 400? If it 400 you must handle response in catch section.